# Using JQuery/JS to move divs from one list to the next

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

I have two lists like so that I can add and remove from.  The starting list can have anywher from 1 to 2,000 variables in it, of the form:

```
<div class="notadded" id="X"><input type="checkbox" />Varname and varlabel</div>
```

I want to move all the checked vars to the next list, removing them from the first list.

What's the best way to do this, given that I could have 2,000 items to move. Also when moving them, I don't want to have any duplicates and preserve the varname's alphabetically (they are loaded that way).

I can also adjust the html anyway I want.

Comment: Do you have *any* ideas?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: i have used .each but that is wwaaaaaaay tooo slow

Comment: i tried this but but are too slow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568319/slow-jquery-function#comment15303961_11568319

Comment: @chris, can you create a jsFiddle with your code? It would be very nice to help with something to change, test and show to you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm trying to guess what you want. So, take a look in this code using jQuery:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="sourceList">
    <div class="notadded" id="1"><input type="checkbox" />Varname and varlabel 1</div>
    <div class="notadded" id="2"><input type="checkbox" />Varname and varlabel 2</div>
    <div class="notadded" id="3"><input type="checkbox" />Varname and varlabel 3</div>
    <div class="notadded" id="4"><input type="checkbox" />Varname and varlabel 4</div>
    <div class="notadded" id="5"><input type="checkbox" />Varname and varlabel 5</div>
    <div class="notadded" id="6"><input type="checkbox" />Varname and varlabel 6</div>
    <div class="notadded" id="7"><input type="checkbox" />Varname and varlabel 7</div>
    <div class="notadded" id="8"><input type="checkbox" />Varname and varlabel 8</div>
    <div class="notadded" id="9"><input type="checkbox" />Varname and varlabel 9</div>
</div>

<input id="moveBtn" type="button" value="Move them!"/>
<input id="removeBtn" type="button" value="Remove them!"/>

<div id="targetList"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function move( sourceSelector, targetSelector ) {
    var selectedItens = $( sourceSelector + " .notadded input:checked" );
    selectedItens.attr( "checked", false );
    $( targetSelector ).append( selectedItens.parent() );
}

$(function() {
    $( "#moveBtn" ).click(function(){
        move( "#sourceList", "#targetList" );
    });

    $( "#removeBtn" ).click(function(){
        move( "#targetList", "#sourceList" );
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/davidbuzatto/Fnxp2/

Is this fast enought?

Comment: I changed the selection expression because it was too big.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how bad this would be for performance on a large scale, what would happen if you had both lists full of the 2000 items but only the first initially visible.

After editing your checkboxes and submitting, you would just go through and change the styles so that they are shown or hidden. My only concern is that this would have excessive amounts of dom elements, but 2000 is already a lot. The advantage of going this way is that there's less dom manipulation other than adding/removing classes and has an added benefit that this maintains the order of the elements in both lists.

I borrowed a lot David's fiddle but adapted it so that there's no new dom elements created [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jvillars/vLce3/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Josh, I changed my selection expression. Take a look. It is smaller now. After seeing your solution, I still think that my solution, even doing the moves, maybe is faster (and simpler) than yours. One good thing of your solution is that the order is maintained. I changed it a bit keeping your solution. Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/davidbuzatto/vLce3/1/